# Tornado & Apache reverse proxy can't get the right configuration

Tags: python, apache, reverse-proxy, tornado

I am using apache to reverse proxy several app and expose only 1 port and 1 ssl certificat. I have manage to make it works for most of the apps but all webapp based on tornado can't follow the reverse proxy addresses.

Let's take an example:
I run my proxy and tornado on the same localhost, port 64646 for the proxy 8080 for tornado app.
I want to have my tornado app on address like that http://localhost:64646/tornado/

The app is working flawless if we directly connect to it.
For example like this : http://localhost:8080/web/

If I use the proxy setting and I type http://localhost:64646/tornado/
I should access the tornado webapp but something break between the webapp and apache and I am redirected to http://localhost:64646/web/auth/login/?next=%2F

The rewriting of URL rule "tornado" part is missing on the address and I can't access the page. That is normal because I am not at the right place.
Also any of static files like css, seems to have the root of the server proxy as reference  and not the relative "Tornado" proxy part.

Similar issue if I enter the full correct address for login :
http://localhost:64646/tornado/auth/login/

The page correctly load but after the authentification I am redirected to

http://localhost:64646/web/index.html instead of http://localhost:64646/tornado/index.html

I certainly miss a stupid configuration but I can't find my mistake. All other webapp are working with my proxy setting only the one made with tornado have this kind of issue.

I can reproduce the issue using the very basic tornado login example and the following apache configuration

webserver.py

```
import tornado.auth
import tornado.escape
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import Settings
import json
import os

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8080, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        params = {
            "title": "proxy test app"
        }
        self.render('index.html', **params)

class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        params = {
            "errormessage": self.get_argument("error", ''),
            "title": "proxy test app"
        }
        self.render('login.html', **params)

    def post(self):
        username = self.get_argument("username", "")
        password = self.get_argument("password", "")
        auth = (username == "admin" and password == "admin")
        if auth:
            self.set_current_user(username)
            self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", u"/web/"))
        else:
            error_msg = u"?error=" + tornado.escape.url_escape("Login incorrect")
            self.redirect(u"/web/auth/login/" + error_msg)

    def set_current_user(self, user):
        if user:
            self.set_secure_cookie("user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
        else:
            self.clear_cookie("user")

class AuthLogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.clear_cookie("user")
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/web/"))

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/web/", MainHandler),
            (r"/web/auth/login/", AuthLoginHandler),
            (r"/web/auth/logout/", AuthLogoutHandler),
        ]
        settings = {
            "template_path":Settings.TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "static_path":Settings.STATIC_PATH,
            "debug":Settings.DEBUG,
            "cookie_secret": Settings.COOKIE_SECRET,
            "login_url": "/web/auth/login/"
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Settings.py

```
import os
DEBUG = True
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'template')

import logging
import sys
#log linked to the standard error stream
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %Hh%Mm%Ss')
console = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
```

/template/login.html

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>{{ title }}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="formContent">
              <!-- Tabs Titles -->
              <!-- Icon -->
              <!-- Login Form -->
              <form action="/web/auth/login/" method="post" id="login_form">
                <input type="text" id="username"  name="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="text" id="password"  name="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
              </form>
              <div >
              <h3 class="active"> {{ errormessage}} </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

/template/index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{ title }}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
              <h3 class="active"> huho ? the droid you are looking for is not here ,,, </h3>
   </body>
 </html>
```

httpd.conf /apache configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:64646>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users\Administrator/Desktop/"
    ServerName proxy-test.com   
    ErrorLog  "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -n 2 logs/https_proxy_error_log.txt 84600 50M"  
    CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -n 2 logs/https_proxy_access.txt 84600 50M" common     
    ProxyHTMLEnable On   
    ProxyPreserveHost On 
    ProxyRequests on   
    #SSLEngine on
    #SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none 
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
        
    #SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
    #SSLCertificateFile "mycrtfile.crt" 
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile "mykeyfile.key" 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    
    ProxyPassMatch    "/otherapp2/(.*)" "http://localhost:30000/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/otherapp2/" "http://localhost:30000/"

    ProxyPassMatch    "/otherapp/(.*)" "http://localhost:8888/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/otherapp/"    "http://localhost:8888"
   
    ProxyPassMatch    "/tornado/(.*)" "http://localhost:8080/web/$1"
    ProxyPassReverse  "/tornado/" "http://localhost:8080/web/"
    
    <location "/otherapp/">
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /otherapp/
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try like this:  `/tornado/hello` --> `apache` --> `/tornado/hello` --> `tornado webapp`.Not : `/tornado/hello/` --> `apache` --> `/hello` --> `tornado webapp`

Comment: I am not sure to understand ? are you speaking about the config file or the http address  ?

Comment: In config file,make the address not change,before in and out.And add start router in webapp's url config.I just do like this

Answer (score 4):

Your Tornado app is sending this redirect - `/auth/login`. But your Apache server doesn't know where to forward this url to because Apache will only forward a url to Tornado app if it starts with `/tornado/`.

To fix this, from the Tornado app, redirect using the complete url: `/tornado/auth/login`.

BTW, you should just prepend the `/tornado/` url prefix to every route of your Tornado app, and from Apache just pass the full url to Tornado. This is a simpler setup. Is there a reason you're not doing this?

**Update:** Here's a diagram to better understand what's going on:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand correctly. The reverse proxy can't do the job to add "tornado"  in the url when the traffic comes back from the tornado app ? 
I have done a simple test with python3 http.server to serve file and configure a reverse proxy. in this case I didn't prepend anything to the http.server but the relative path are working.
let's say I configure my proxy with files/ for all requests from the http.server they are correclty following the url schema.
Of course I can rewrite with the prepend but my goal is to not rewrite the tornado app.

Comment: I have also done a quick test using python3 -m http.server to serve a directory on the server and configure apache to route all url to /files/ from to the python server.
And this simple server behave correclty in the proxy , all my url are with the files/ tag. 
And I didn't tell the http.server anything about the routing ? did I miss something in the behavior of the apache routing process ?

Comment: @cnaimi Your Tornado server is returning `/auth/login` redirect whereas it should return `/tornado/auth/login`.

Comment: @cnaimi I've added a diagram in my answer to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. I was confused by the redirection and the response from other app that act differently. it's more clear now.

Comment: Hi, I have try to change the code as you suggest by adding /web/ (for example) on all my routing in the tornado app. But even with this I still have the issue on apache the re-routing is not working and I endup in the wrong URL in the proxy.

Comment: @cnaimi Because now the form url is `/web/auth/login/` (starts with `/web/`) but Apache expects `/tornado/auth/login/`. Both urls do not match.